# disable transform in rectangle selection tool

Tags: adobe-photoshop, selections, text-wrap

I am new in Photoshop,
I wanna turn over the corner of the gray square.
first, I draw rectangular marquee tool and second, press Ctrl+T but as you can see the small squares appear in the corner of gray square instead of rectangular marquee.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to transform the **selection** and not the layer itself - in other words, alter the selection not what's inside it -  choose `Select > Transform Selection`.

The standard transform (command/Ctrl-t) always transforms the *layer contents*.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to control-click on your Shape 1 layer and select Rasterize Layer from the menu, then, when you'll make a selection (marquee) on that same layer, you will be able to CTRL-T (Transform) your selection, rotate or modify it the way you want.

Hope this helps!